# Three.js - Control camera motion with device tilting / gyroscope on mobile

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

i have simple 3d project made in three.js.

Currently its controlled by mouse motion which rotates camera around the scene (this also works by touch on mobile).

I want to implement to control this basic camera movement to be controlled by device motion / tilting / gyroscope while accesing web on mobile devices.

Here is my code:

```
const nearDist = 0.1;
const farDist = 10000;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    55,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    nearDist,
    farDist
);
camera.position.x = farDist * -2;
camera.position.z = 500;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor("#e8a82b"); 
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio); 
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.querySelector("#canvas-wrapper").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Object
const cubeSize = 300;
const geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(cubeSize, 0 ); // BufferAttribute allows for more efficient passing of data to the GPU
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({roughness: 1});
const group = new THREE.Group();
for (let i = 0; i < 260; i++) {
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    const dist = farDist / 3;
    const distDouble = dist * 2;
    const tau = 2 * Math.PI; // One turn

    mesh.position.x = Math.random() * distDouble - dist;
    mesh.position.y = Math.random() * distDouble - dist;
    mesh.position.z = Math.random() * distDouble - dist;
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.random() * tau;
    mesh.rotation.y = Math.random() * tau;
    mesh.rotation.z = Math.random() * tau;

    // Manually control when 3D transformations recalculation occurs for better performance
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    mesh.updateMatrix();

    group.add(mesh);
}
scene.add(group);
// Typo
const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh();
const createTypo = font => {
    const word = "be creative";
    const typoProperties = {
        font: font,
        size: cubeSize,
        height: cubeSize / 2,
        curveSegments: 16
    };
    const text = new THREE.TextGeometry(word, typoProperties);
    textMesh.geometry = text;
    textMesh.material = material;
    textMesh.position.x = cubeSize * -2;
    textMesh.position.z = cubeSize * -1;
    scene.add(textMesh);
};
loader.load(
    "https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json",
    createTypo
);

// Mouse move
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0;
const mouseFX = {
    windowHalfX: window.innerWidth / 2,
    windowHalfY: window.innerHeight / 2,
    coordinates: function(coordX, coordY) {
        mouseX = (coordX - mouseFX.windowHalfX) * 2;
        mouseY = (coordY - mouseFX.windowHalfY) * 2;
    },
    onMouseMove: function(e) {
        mouseFX.coordinates(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    },
    onTouchMove: function(e) {
        mouseFX.coordinates(e.changedTouches[0].clientX, e.changedTouches[0].clientY);
    }
};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseFX.onMouseMove, false);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", mouseFX.onTouchMove, false);
// Render
const render = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    // Camera animation
    camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * 0.05;
    camera.position.y += (mouseY * -1 - camera.position.y) * 0.05;
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    const t = Date.now() * 0.001;
    const rx = Math.sin(t * 0.6) * 0.5;
    const ry = Math.sin(t * 0.3) * 0.5;
    const rz = Math.sin(t * 0.2) * 0.5;
    group.rotation.x = rx;
    group.rotation.y = ry;
    group.rotation.z = rz;
    textMesh.rotation.x = rx;
    textMesh.rotation.y = ry;
    textMesh.rotation.z = rx; // :) 

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
render();


const resizeCanvas = () => {
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
};
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);
```

I tried to implement [threeVR library](https://github.com/richtr/threeVR) but without any luck. But since this is my first three.js prject i belive i did it something wrong. I couldnt find any other solution for this.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I also tried to implement device orientation controls - https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/DeviceOrientationControls but couldnt make it work

Comment: What device are you using? I believe iPhones only allow device orientation listeners if you're connecting via `https`. See here for a discussion on the matter: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/iphone-ios-12-2-will-disable-gyroscope-access-by-default/6579

Comment: i can't make it work on any device and website is using ssl, if there is need for users co confirm usage of gyroscope, thats ok. I just cant get it to work. Everytime i try to edit my code and implement device orientation control my whole three.js  canvas won't load so i belive i cant quite get the implementation of device control going

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you're setting `"deviceorientation"` event listeners. I only see `"mousemove" & "touchmove"` events. Are you sure you're implementing orientation events correctly?

Comment: actually im sure of the opposite, im sure i implemented it wrong, and code i provided is without it because i didnt want to show something that is obvioulsy wrong since i belive there is some simple solution that will work but i dont know what it is